# Change a data type through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the `data-title` to "Projects" through jQuery.

```
<a id="contact-button" href="#" data-title="Contact">Get in touch</a>
```

I've tried something like this but it didn't work. Is there a way?

```
$('#contact-button').data('title', 'Projects').text('Projects');
```

Comment: try this `$('#contact-button').attr('data-title', 'Projects').text('Projects');`

Comment: This looks a lot like an XY problem. How did you confirm that it didn't work and what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The code needs more context. What is using data-title? When is it called? how is it called? etc.. That code above should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#contact-button').attr('data-title', 'Projects').text('Projects');
```